# How to check if the program is running with Administrator privileges in Swift

Tags: swift, command-line

I'm trying to make an installation script in Swift for my program (that is also made in Swift).

What it simply does is create a new folder in `Library/` and then clones the GitHub repository there.

The problem is that for doing anything in `Library/` you need administrator rights. That's why I want to check if the program is running with administrator rights, so if it doesn't, throw an error telling the user to run it using `sudo`.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import Darwin

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

func Main() {
    if CommandLine.arguments[0] == "sudo" { //I tried by using this, but it seems that sudo doesn't appear in CommandLine.arguments
        print("Welcome to the MoonFish installation... This will install MoonFish on /Library/MoonFish/ using 59.37 MB")
        shell("mkdir", "/Library/MoonFish")
        shell("git", "clone https://github.com/iAlex11/MoonFish.git /Library/MoonFish/") //clones MoonFish repo
    } else {
        print("\u{001B}[1;31mError:\u{001B}[0;0m Please run this program using sudo. Example: sudo ./install")
        exit(0)
    }
}

Main()
```

Comment: You cannot run `Process()` tasks with administrator privileges.

Comment: @vadian So, what should I do?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow to run tasks with elevated rights via `Process`.

I recommend to use AppleScript.

- Launch Script Editor.
- Copy and paste this code.

  ```
  try
      display dialog "Welcome to the MoonFish installation... This will install MoonFish on /Library/MoonFish/ using 59.37 MB" buttons {"Cancel", "Install"} default button 2
      do shell script "/bin/mkdir /Library/MoonFish" with administrator privileges
      do shell script "/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/iAlex11/MoonFish.git /Library/MoonFish/" with administrator privileges
  on error
      quit
  end try
  ```
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- From Menu `File` choose `Export`.
- In the dialog check `Run Only` and select `Application` from the `File Format` popup.
- Specify a file name and a location and Press <kbd>Save</kbd>.

You can even use a custom icon. Replace `./Contents/Resources/applet.icns` with another `applet.icns` file.